# Почему в gcc это работает?

Tags: c, gcc, инициализация

Статический массив с размером, не известным на момент компиляции.
char buf[atoi(argv[2])];
И где можно про это почитать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `buf` является локальной (автоматической) переменной, то вы имеете дело с обыкновенным VLA - Variable Length Array - появившимся в языке C в стандарте C99. Начиная с C11 поддержка VLA является *опциональной*.

Назвать таком массив "статическим" более чем неуместно. VLA не могут быть статическими. Только автоматические массивы могут быть VLA.

P.S. Тэг `[инициализация]` тут как раз таки не уместен - объявления VLA не допускают указания инициализатора.

Answer (score 1):

Всё расписано в стандарте

```
# include <stddef.h>

/*
 6.10.8.3
 Conditional feature macros    
__STDC_NO_VLA__ Если определена константой 1, то означает, что компилятор не
поддерживает VLA или типы плавающего размера.*/

# ifdef __STDC_NO_VLA__
# error Упс VLA не поддерживаем
# else
# warning VLA поддерживается
# endif

/* C standard
  6.5.3.4
  The sizeof and _Alignof operators
 */
size_t fsize3(int n) {
  char b[n+3];
  return sizeof b; }

// variable length array
// execution time sizeof
int main() {
  size_t size;
  size = fsize3(10); // fsize3 returns 13
  return 0; }  

/*
 6.7.6.2 

Если размер это целочисленная константное выражение и тип элемента имеет известный
 константный размер, то тип массива не VLA; иначе VLA. (VLA может не
 поддерживаться; см. 6.10.8.3.) 


6.7.8 Определение типа

    Если тип определённый с помощью typedef имеет тип VLA, длина этого типа
 фиксирована в момент определения. При изменении значения переменной,
 задававшей размер массива, тип не изменится.

*/
void copyt(int n) {
  typedef int B[n]; // B is n ints, n evaluated now
  n += 1;
  B a;  // a is n ints, n without += 1
  int b[n];  // a and b are different sizes
  for (int i = 1; i < n;i++)
    a[i-1] = b[i]; }
```