# Почему нельзя создать массив произвольной длины в С++ ( и не только )

Tags: c++

Как новичок, столкнулся с проблемой, что если на момент компиляции кода размер массива не известен, то конструкция в виде

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int arr[n];
```

просто не сработает. Но мне очень бы хотелось, чтобы размер массива задавал конечный пользователь, не используя при этом библиотеку классов STL или реализацию через указатели. Я знаю, что для этого следовало бы использовать динамический массив или список. Но меня интересует вопрос: чем обусловлено такое ограничение? Почему компилятор не дает создать такую конструкцию?

Comment: @Harry, это вы к чему?

Comment: ещё один ответ, что ли написать?

Comment: Если очень хочется, то используйте Си

Comment: используйте операто new для создания подобного массива

Answer (score 4):

Технически создать такой массив *можно*. В языке С, начиная с версии С99, такое массивы  - VLA - прекрасно поддерживаются. Так что никакого "нельзя" тут нет. (Тема полезности и недостатков таких массивов в С - отдельная тема.)

В языке С++ же такие массивы просто запрещены. Причина того, почему языке С++ нет массивов run-time размера кроются, скорее всего, в тонкостях процесса типизации и инициализации.

О тонкостях типизации я писал [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/928789/182825).

В том же языке С, например, запрещается указывать инициализатор в объявлении VLA, ибо нет хорошего решения по семантике "лишних" инициализаторов (если вдруг какие-то из них окажутся лишними.)

В языке С++, где инициализация существенно боле важна и устроена существенно более сложно, такие массивы решили не поддерживать вообще.

Comment: Кажется, в g++ всё сделали: https://ideone.com/B3akan :)

Comment: @Qwertiy Во-первых, это только кажется. Во-вторых, внутренние фантазии GCC к языку никакого отношения не имеют.

Comment: Я и не говорил про язык. Я имел в виду, что при желании сделать всё сделали. Т. е. по-моему причины запрета не технические, а чисто идеологические. А в чём заключается _"это только кажется"_?

Answer (score 3):

> Почему компилятор не дает создать такую конструкцию?

Надо различать решения, принимаемые на стадии компиляции, и решения, принимаемые на стадии выполнения. По классике решения по всем типам переменных и размерам массивов принимаются на стадии компиляции. Преимущества такого подхода - программист полностью контролирует все действия компилятора и понимает, сколько времени и места занимает создание того или иного объекта.

Конечно, есть языки в которых все определяется на стадии выполнения, в том числе и типы переменных и размеры всех объектов (в том числе и массивов). Недостатки такого подхода - для обеспечения такой функциональности внутри вызывается громадная библиотека, которая пасет все переменные и массивы. При этом программист не контролирует время выполнения объектов и код перестает быть полностью управляемым.

Одно из базовых правил языков С/С++ - "в коде нет ничего, что программист не заказывал бы явно". Да и то это правило нарушается - например статические объекты ВСЕГДА инициализируются нулями. Для десктопа это может быть и не так важно, так как старт программы с диска все равно операция не реального времени. А для встроенных систем это может быть критично, например питание на систему уже подано, а процессор вместо того чтобы уже начать управлять защитой атомного реактора в это время старательно записывает нули в статические переменные.

> с чем связано такое ограничение, а не то, как его обойти / решить

Ну так вот, это ограничение связано с желанием иметь полную управляемость кода и точное понимание, где какой вызов библиотеки будет вставлен, а где не будет. И также с желанием отказаться от всех вызовов библиотек, если это нужно для программиста.

А обойти это очень просто - используйте оператор new или библиотеку STL. Там есть массивы переменного размера. Или переходите на языки без статической типизации переменных.

UPD1:

Я тут решил уточнить, в чем проблемы при создании массива переменного размера на стеке. Предположим, есть функция:

```
    void fun(int a){

    int b;
    int c;

    int array[a];

/*какой-то код*/  
    }
```

Вроде бы все нормально, просто надо передать переменное значение при создании стекового кадра. Но если после массива с переменной длинной есть еще переменные, то доступ к ним уже невозможно получить зная лишь константные смещения в стековом кадре. Необходимо учитывать длину массива array, а это и есть тот самый дополнительный код, который программист не заказывал. Например:

```
    void fun(int a){

    int b;
    int c;

    int array[a];

    int d;
    int e;


/*какой-то код*/  
    }
```

В этом примере для доступа к переменным "d" и "e" нельзя использовать константные смещения в стековом кадре. Нужна специальная функция для расчета смещений, в зависимости от параметра "a". Если же массивов переменной размерности в стеке несколько, то ситуация еще более усложняется. Например:

```
    void fun1(int a, int a1){

    int b;
    int c;

    int array[a];

    int d;
    int e;

    int array1[a1];

    int f;
    int g;

/*какой-то код*/  
    }
```

В этом примере смещение при доступе к переменным "f" и "g" должно зависеть от параметров "a" и "a1".

Поэтому для исключения лишних вычислений при доступе к переменным (то есть для повышения быстродействия и исключения явно не заказанных вызовов библиотек) создание массивов переменной длинны на стеке запрещено.

UPD2:

> Однако, в Си VLA есть (и как это соотносится с вашими объяснениями
>   причин?)

Объяснение одно - в далеком 1972 году Ритчи и Томпсон решили не заморачиваться поддержкой VLA. Потом уже другие люди поглядели и сказали - "VLA сделать можно, давайте сделаем. А если кто-то не хочет, чтобы ему подключалось в оверхед вычисление смещения в каждом стековом кадре, тот просто не будет использовать VLA". Это так же, как с оверхедом при использовании виртуальных функций. Кто не хочет, чтобы у него был оверхед при использовании виртуальных функций, тот не использует виртуальные функции. Просто надо понимать, в чем тут оверхед и соответственно принимать решение, что в данный момент важнее (и быстрее) - иметь VLA или доступ к каждой стековой переменной будет в 10 раз дольше.

UPD3:

> ваше утверждение "...доступ к каждой стековой переменной будет в 10
>   раз дольше..." к какому компилятору относится?

Да к любому компилятору это относится. Если стековый кадр переменной длинны, то хочешь-не хочешь а надо вычислять смещения в рантайме.

У меня GCC не развернут, так что я проверить не могу. А Вы попробуйте странслировать второй пример, который я привел, с двумя массивами VLA в функции fun1. Там должно быть как минимум два умножения, два сложения и пересылки между регистрами, чтобы косвенно-индексную адресацию реализовать. Причем количество операций линейно растет в зависимости от количества массивов VLA в функции. Если вычисление смещения будет оформлено как подпрограмма, то добавится еще вход-выход в подпрограмму. Надо еще учесть, что сама выборка дополнительных команд занимает время. Так что десятикратное увеличение времени доступа это еще оптимистичная оценка. Напомню, что доступ к стековым переменным в случае константных смещений занимает одну инструкцию и в общем виде (без привязки к конкретной архитектуре) имеет вид (условно):

```
mov ax, k(sp)
```

где "k" это и есть то самое константное смещение переменной в стековом кадре.

> Количество команд для извлечения элемента что обычного, что
>   VLA-массива одно и то же -- ровно одна movl.)

Надо смотреть не количество команд для извлечения элементов VLA массива, а количество команд для доступа к другим переменным в стековом кадре у той функции, у которой определен VLA массив.

UPD4:

> Уже во время выполнения происходит выделение памяти под VLA

Так что это, GCC размещает VLA массив в куче? Это вообще не честно, так как весь смысл в том, чтобы кучу не трогать. Операция обращения к куче это долгая операция, а операция выделения стекового кадра это копейки. Вобщем при размещении VLA массива в куче, конечно, никакого оверхеда для доступа к стековым переменным не будет. Зато будет конский оверхед (десятки миллисекунд на современной винде) из-за размещения и удаления массива в куче. И вообще, какой смысл размещать VLA массив в куче, если можно явно вызвать malloc? Вобщем это профанация, а не VLA массивы. Фу, фу, фу я был гораздо лучшего мнения о GCC.

Comment: Однако, в Си VLA есть (и как это соотносится с вашими объяснениями причин?)

Comment: @avp, как и в плюсах при желании: https://ideone.com/B3akan

Comment: Вроде бы на размещение и порядок переменных никаких требований нет. Они могу даже в регистрах лежать при необходимости. А для примитивов могут и пообъединяться, возможно.

Comment: @Qwertiy,  не знал! В самом деле, работает, начиная с `g++ t.cpp -std=c++11`. / Что же, дружно минусуем (или просим поправить) свои ответы всех авторов?

Comment: @avp, ответы вроде верные, это g++ выпендривается)))

Comment: @Qwertiy, пожалуй это самый распространенный в мире компилятор. Раз ему можно, то что тогда считать кошерными крестами?

Comment: @pepsicoca1, ваше утверждение *`"...доступ к каждой стековой переменной будет в 10 раз дольше..."`* к какому компилятору относится? / (Я посмотрел простой пример с `gcc -S -Os` в x86-64 для доступа по индексу, возвращаемому внешней функцией. Количество команд для извлечения элемента что обычного, что VLA-массива одно и то же -- ровно одна `movl`.)

Comment: Не знаю, какой у вас компайлер, но gcc сначала размещает в стеке (с известным во время компиляции смещением) все обычные стековые переменные и дескрипторы VLA массивов. Поэтому время доступа ко всем ним не зависит от наличия и размеров VLA. Уже во время выполнения происходит выделение памяти под VLA и в соответствующий дескриптор (вообще говоря, он может быть выброшен оптимизатором, если регистров хватает) заносится адрес размещаемого VLA. / Кстати, можете попечатать адреса переменных в вашей функции `fun1()` для разных ее параметров и посмотреть, как себя ведет ваш компайлер

Comment: @pepsicoca1, где вы нашли выделение памяти из кучи? Ни в `.s` (слишком велик для показа в комментарии), ни в выводе `nm test-vla.o` -- `avp@avp-xubu2:~/hashcode$ nm test-vla.o
0000000000000000 T f
0000000000000030 T f1
                 U f2
0000000000000050 T fun1
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
0000000000000000 r .LC0
0000000000000000 T main
                 U __printf_chk
                 U strtol` я в упор ничего подобного не наблюдаю

Comment: @avp Может быть стоит написать свой ответ и привести код GCC? А то у нас беспредметный разговор получается.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, о чем тут писать? Что VLA на самом дел работает (по крайней мере в gcc)? Все грамотные люди это знают. Про остальное написал Qwertiy *`"Т. е. по-моему причины запрета не технические, а чисто идеологические."`* в своем комментарии к ответу AnT / Вот и весь сказ...

Comment: Стек – самая дефицитная память, поэтому часто приходится даже извращаться с размещением в куче параметров. Дичь полнейшая, но иначе стека не хватает в миллионы раз. А в куче можно размешать многие гигабайты.

Answer (score 0):

Динамические массивы никто не запрещал, но создаются они не так. Декларации, в том числе,

```
int arr[n];
```

обрабатываются на этапе компиляции. Это необходимо для того, чтоб знать, как разместить код и данные и какого размера создать файл с исполняемым кодом программы. Что там в голых сях костыляют вместо возможности завернуть динамический массив в класс, меня не касается, плюсы – не голые си и даже не си с классами (обджектив си), на них можно всё сделать правильно, не пряча динамическое выделение памяти под странные синтаксические конструкции. Бейсик не компилируемый, а интерпретируемый, соответственно, он по стандарту транслируется на этапе исполнения, поэтому там любой dim – это операция, а не декларация, поэтому там запрещены как раз статические массивы (статическим называется массив с постоянным количеством элементов, он может быть и автоматической переменной). Даже если кажется, что такая-то реализация компилиуемая, а на самом деле программа собирается в единое целое с интерпретатором. Даже если такая-то версия действительно компилируемая в нечто, полностью имитирующее интерпретацию, что опять ведёт к операции dim вместо декларации. Но плюсы – и не бейсик, на них приходится компилировать всё заранее, а только потом запускать, а переменные – декларировать, а не исполнять. Но кроме автоматических переменных есть ещё динамические переменные, они размещаются в куче. И память для них по определению выделяется на этапе исполнения. Вот их и надо использовать для динамических массивов. Простейший способ – декларировать массив как указатель, а потом выделить по этому указателю память для самого массива оператором new и после использования её освободить.

```
    size_t n;
    int *arr;
    cin >> n;
    arr=new (std::nowthrow) int [n];
    if (arr)
    {
     delete [] arr;
    }
    else
    {
     std::cout<<"Не могу выделить память."<<std::endl;
    }
```

между открывающей фигурной скобкой и

```
delete [] arr;
```

пишите всю работу с массивом. Не хотите таскать указатель по всему коду? Ол комплит, изучайте классы. В том числе, некоторые готовые.

Comment: И все же, g++ поддерживает VLA (тот самый `int arr[n];`. где величина `n` не известна при компиляции)

Comment: А мелкосовтоские компиляторы знают тип hyper.

Comment: Я, конечно, не знаком с MS компайлерами, но слышал, что в отличии от GNU они реализованы не повсеместно. Машинки же или ОС  без GCC в последние лет 30 мне не встречалось.

Comment: Это не значит, в нем нет фигни. Нафига там такие массивы? Также, как не нужен фирменный hyper, вместо него достаточно uint128_t. Любой нормальный программист ожидает, что int arr[n]; будет декларацией, а не операцией. Выглядит-то также, как и в том случае, когда n  – константа. А читать каждый раз весь исходник для понимания такой простой строчки – верный способ через пару лет остановить разработку.

Comment: Причём. явное выделение динамической памяти работает вообще везде, включая не только gcc для других платформ, но и чужие компиляторы для той же оси. А вот с VLA можно долго разбираться, почему его какой-то елвый компил не понимает, а только часа три понять, что это ж и не gcc, и не мелкософт.

Comment: На что не пойдешь ради оптимизации -). А насчет *`Любой нормальный программист ожидает, что int arr[n]; будет декларацией, а не операцией.`* -- что-то в этом утверждении есть... Но, тогда и и блоки кода (в `{...}` особенно вложенные, с объявлением в них скаляров) тоже должны вас коробить.

Comment: С выделение динамической памяти везде -- тут вы не правы. В некоторых embedded malloc не реализован (и стандартных библиотек вообще нет). Конечно, всегда можно прикрутить самому, но часто руки не доходят...

Comment: То есть левый. Очепятка.

Comment: Я похож на пришельца с планеты адептов бейсика? Блок – он и в Африке блок, для его понимания не надо лезть выше, наоборот, он необходим для декомпозиции. Ну если разбираемся именно с этим куском, то да, надо лезть прямо в блок. Но тогда другие куски пофиг. А что такое int arr[n];, сколько суток он будет выполняться и может ли через годик внезапно начать ронять всю приладу должно быть понятно непосредственно из этого фрагмента без попыток выяснить, сколько в проекте всего разнообразных n, каких они типов, чему и когда равны и в какой области видимости находится каждый из них.

Comment: И не надо кивать на помощь среды, не рушить на корню всю декомпозицию должен сам текст.

Comment: И как же на таких системах работают хоть какие-то компиляторы языка с указателями и оператором new?

Comment: Они работают без new. С указателями проблем нет. Но, лично я не люблю кресты и предпочитаю чистый сишный код. Насчет производительности VLA -- создание это просто сдвинуть SP и занести его в дескриптор VLA (структура в том же месте памяти, гда был бы массив с фиксированным размером). Да, для доступа лишняя загрузка базы из дескриптора в регистр (обычно оптимизатор при достаточном количестве регистровхорошо  минимизирует такие загрузки)

Comment: А без функций можно работать? Оператор new – часть языка. Всякие там решётки могут работать без чего угодно, но плюсы должны быть с new.

Comment: Авторы компиляторов не согласны с вами. Самому по себе крестовому компайлеру (и GNU, и Synopsys MetaWare) new не нужен. Он появляется из STL (который в таких системах не используется)

Comment: Крестовому, может, и не нужен. А плюсовому обязателен.

Comment: [C++ damages the brain … – EWD](http://harmful.cat-v.org/software/c++/) (EWD это Дейктра, если что)

Comment: Он автор языка?

Comment: Или он автор книги по языку? Шилдт же почему-то внёс new в список ключевых слов языка.

Comment: Вы не слышали о [Дэйкстре](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0,_%D0%AD%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B3%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B5)? (а кто такой Шилдт? -) (шутка)) / Но то, что new ключевое слово и компилятор знает, что его надо реализовывать вызывая malloc (если другой аллокатор не указан) вы правы

Comment: Просто программист не обязан использовать new/delete/ Можно писать и без них (и без VLA тоже). Зависит от задачи

Answer (score -3):

> не используя при этом библиотеку классов STL или реализацию через
>   указатели.

Какое то странное ограничение. Писать на C++ и не использовать cout, vector, map, ... давайте ещё от ООП откажемся, и что останется?

Собственно этой мой ответ - ООП, не хотите STL - рисуйте свой std::array / std::vector. В чём проблема?

Как там, `malloc` / `delete`,`new` / `delete`,`xalloc` / `delete`, ох, не забыть бы `delete`.... может взять stl и RAII? может это всё извращение? может нервные клетки и правда не восстанавливаюцца? ох, ладна.... нет... продолжим... `new` / `delete`,`new` / `delete`,`new` / `delete`...

Ведь язык C++ это язык высокого уровне - не с проста... это говорит о том, что программист может сам нарисовать, используя Объектно-ориентированное программирование, все объекты которые ему необходимы, а затем делать всё что вздумаеться ему с этими объектами.

К слову сам STL написан на C++, ограничение - не использовать STL - это всё равно что - не использовать язык C++, нет?

Comment: какое это имеет отношения к вопросу?