# Задание размера статического массива run-time значением

Tags: c++, массивы, runtime

К чему может привести, или вообще ни к чему не приведёт, задание размера статического массива значением, которое станет известно лишь на этапе выполнения программы?

Знаю лишь то, что это не по стандарту языка `C++`, в `C` это вполне себе законно.

Примером будет выступать вот такой код:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    T arr[n];


    /*код, включающий в себя работу с массивом arr*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В си это не законно, это просто расширения компиляторов которые позволяют так делать. С `GCC` этот код компилируется, однако не под всеми версиями, а компилятор от майкрософт, честно вам отдаст ошибку. Для `C++` есть вектор, которому вы можете прямо во время выполнения менять размер, при помощи метода `resize`.

Comment: Вектора использовать умею. Дело в том, что на недавнем уроке информатики моему классу рассказывали о том, что не пишите так, мол, программа даже если компилируется, то будет работать неправильно. Я возразил, что это лишь будет код, написанный в несогласовании со стандартом языка, т.к. такое утверждение встречал когда-то на этом сайте. Кстати, в мой лицей один человек не попал лишь из-за того, что в письменном экзамене по информатике он написал стат. массив с длиной, вводимой с клавиатуры :). Ещё один вопрос: если всё таки скомпилировалась, то работать будет без никаких undefined behaviour?

Comment: @ヒミコ: Кто вам такое сказал? Такие массивы - VLA - являются стандартным свойством языка C начиная с C99. Начиная с C11 их поддержка опциональна, но это не делает их менее стандартными.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В языке С++ такие массивы не поддерживаются

В типичной традиционной реализации VLA в языке C определение локального VLA

```
T arr[n];
```

будет втихаря заменено компилятором на два определения локальных переменных

```
size_t __size_arr;
T *arr;
```

Размер массива будет сохранен во внутренней переменной `__size_arr`

```
size_t __size_arr = n;
```

(то есть таким образом будет запомнено, каким было значение `n` в тот момент, когда управление проходило по вашему объявлению).

А память для самого массива будет выделена на вершине стека при помощи некоей внутренней платформенно-зависимой функциональности вроде `alloca`

```
T *arr = alloca(__size_arr * sizeof(T));
```

Также, в точке(-ах) выхода из блока, содержащего определение такого массива (таких массивов), компилятор сгенерирует код, возвращающий вершину стека в то положение, в котором она находилась при входе в этот блок, т.е. фактически освобождающий весь стек, выделенный для VLA в этом блоке.

Вычисление размера такого массива через `sizeof arr` будет порождать выражение вида

```
__size_arr * sizeof(T)
```

значение которого будет вычисляться во время выполнения. Если аргумент такого `sizeof` имеет побочные эффекты, то они возымеют место во время выполнения

```
unsigned n = 42;
unsigned a[n];
unsigned s = sizeof(*(printf("Hello World\n"), &a));
// Напечатает "Hello World"
```

Также, по понятным причинам, компилятор не позволит вам передавать управление (`goto` или `switch`) в области видимости таких массивов через объявления таких массивов и объявления соответствующих типов

```
goto skip; // Ошибка: нелегальный `goto`

unsigned n = 42;
unsigned a[n];

skip:;
```

(Подробнее см. здесь: [Как работает VLA?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/909166/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-vla/928789#928789))

Также, язык накладывает определенные ограничения на использование стандартных функций `setjmp`/`longjmp` в присутствии VLA.

Comment: Круто! Ещё и узнал про то, как можно явно выделять место в стеке.

Comment: Не совсем понятен пункт, начинающийся со слов "Также, по понятным причинам". Что значит передавать управление ЧЕРЕЗ объявления таких массивов? соответствующие типы чему?

Comment: @markussie Речь идёт об объявлениях VLA массивов и typedef-объявлениях VLA типов. В ответе по ссылке я как раз приводил пример с `goto`, перепрыгивающим через VLA `typedef`. Он приводит к ошибке компиляции.

Comment: @markussie: Помните только, что если вы сами будете выделять память в стеке через `alloca`, то освобождаться автоматически в конце блока эта память не будет. Такая память освободится только при выходе из функции. Так что воспроизвести свойства стандартных VLA при помощи одного только `alloca` у вас не получится.

Comment: Где-то я видел требование вообще не использовать `alloca` и  VLA в одной и той же функции

Comment: @avp: Да, тот факт, что стек освобождается оптом по принципу LIFO, ожидаемо приведет к тому, что освобождения VLA будут "рушить" функциональность `alloca`, заодно освобождая и эту память тоже. В принципе, поведение там скорее всего с предсказуемое и логичное, но тем не менее время жизни `alloca` памяти становится совсем другим.

Comment: GCC, однако, поступает наоборот, насколько я вижу. Приоритет отдается функциональности `alloca`: достаточно применить в коде `alloca`, и компилятор просто перестает освобождать VLA в конце блока.