# Почему нельзя использовать значение, введенное пользователем для создания массива?

Tags: c++

Везде говорится что в c++ при создании массива размер должен быть известен во время компиляции, то есть размер должен быть константой. Но почему тогда значение введенное пользователем прекрасно подходит для создания массива?

```
int n = 1;
cin >> n;
char str[n];
cout << sizeof(str) << endl;
```

Ввожу `100` и `sizeof` возвращает также `100`, а должен вроде как вернуть `1`. Что я не понимаю?

Comment: Этот код не является валидным в С++. Видимо вы используете GNUсное расширение VLA.

Comment: Некоторые компиляторы поддерживают массивы переменной длины в качестве расширения. Такая поддержка не требуется стандартами языков C/C++, и vc++ их и не поддерживает. [Пример](https://rextester.com/HGCFV97003).

Comment: Радуйтесь, вы пользуетесь правильным компилятором

Comment: Если найдёте [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/909166/176217) ответ, то можно закрыть дубликатом.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, в комментариях уже ответили на вопрос, можно закрывать(я не могу это сделать)