# std::array с динамическим размером

Tags: c++, массивы

nrT я хочу чтобы задал человек, а не чтобы была готовая цифра. (мне постоянно выдает ошибку, что не статический член)

```
int nrt{};
std::array<T, nrT>
```

я думал записать как:

```
const int nrT{};
```

н тоже не работает

Comment: Ну вы же вроде бы человек, вот вы и  задаете. В чем проблема?

Comment: @こきん проблема в том, что мне выдает ошибку(std::array<T, nrT>), а так ошибки нет (std::array<T, 5>). я хочу чтобы человек задавал nrT

Comment: Используйте `std::vector`, размер `std::array` должен быть константой времени компиляции.

Comment: А вы читали что этот контейнер представляет из себя? Это просто обертка над простым массивом на стеке, если не подходит используйте другие контейнеры, которые умеют динамически выделять память. https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array

Comment: @user7860670 спасибо

Comment: @こきん просто в задании стоит именно так :( а так я бы вектор использовал

Comment: Тогда покажите фото задания, желательно с именем преподавателя

Comment: А вот в Си есть [VLA](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/909166/235436)

Comment: `#include <vector>` и ниже `namespace std { using array = vector; }`
А дальше, можно наколоть автора задания.

Comment: но даже этот трюк не позволит передать в угловые скобки переменную

Answer (score 1):

Это невозможно по определению, так как параметр шаблона должен быть известен во время компиляции.

Воспользуйтесь `std::vector`