# Создание массива в функции на стеке с разным размером

Tags: c++

```
void foo(int b)
{
  static int a = 10;
  a += b; // or a = b
  int mass[a];
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) mass[i] = i;
  for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) std::cout << mass[i] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::string count;
  // 1
  std::cout << "Enter a size of array: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> count;
  foo(std::stoi(count));
  // 2
  std::cout << "Enter a size of array: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> count;
  foo(std::stoi(count));
  return 0;
}
```

Не совсем понимаю почему это работает. Ведь для создания массива на стеке assembler заранее должен знать какой размер у этого массива будет. Тут же значение массива не известно, пока его не введет пользователь.
Добрые жители StackOverflow, прошу объясните мне..

Comment: компиляторы терпят такие коды, потому-что в Си такое можно делать, и если не ставить опцию компилировать по стандарту то будет пахать.

Comment: Так это в gcc, наверное, за счет его расширений. При соблюдении соответствия стандарту это компилироваться не станет.

Comment: в ассемблере всё просто `add rsp , "a" * 4` и всё.

Comment: На этом же сайте есть вопрос [Как работает VLA?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/909166/232), на который дан [шикарный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/928789/232) / От себя могу добавить, VLA это в самом деле удобно, просто используйте [правильный компилятор](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) (к тому же, он самый распростаненный в этом мире)

Comment: @avp спасибо за ссылку на вопрос

Comment: @Harry понял, благодарю, попробую на другом компиляторе

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С простыми типами, какие есть в Си компиляторы прощают нестандартный код и пишут код так-же как в Си. Нужно просто поднять вершину стека на нужное количество байт.

```asm
mov     rbp, rsp
push    r12
push    rbx
add     edi, DWORD PTR foo(int)::a[rip]
movsx   rax, edi
mov     DWORD PTR foo(int)::a[rip], edi
lea     rax, [15+rax*4]
and     rax, -16
sub     rsp, rax
```

Команда `lea     rax, [15+rax*4]` вычисляет нужное число для увеличивания границы вершины стека и простым вычитанием  `sub     rsp, rax` это делает.

*В Си это до сих пор законно, а в C++ нет. Не рекомендуется писать несовместимо. Другой компилятор просто не сможет это сделать.*

---

*Добавление `+15` и `and -16` нужно для увеличивания вершины, кратным 16.*

Comment: Примерно понял, еще постараюсь разобраться в этом коде. Спасибо большое за исчерпывающий ответ 