# Удаление динамического массива, объявленного через нотацию массива arr[x][y]

Tags: c++, динамические-массивы, c++17, delete

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int cities;
    cin >> cities;

    int mas[cities][cities];

    for (int i = 0; i < cities; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cities; ++j) {
            mas[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

for (int i = 0; i < cities; ++i) {
    delete[] mas[i]; // ERROR: Cannot delete expression of type 'int[cities]'
}
delete[] mas; // ERROR: Cannot delete expression of type 'int[cities][cities]'

    return 0;
}
```

Поскольку `cities` не известна на этапе компиляции, то компилятор в строке `int mas[cities][cities];` создает (автоматически) динамический массив, верно? Или что он создает? Почему я его не могу удалить в конце программы с помощью `delete[]`?

`mas` получает тип `int(*)[cities]`, а `mas[0]` получает тип `int *`. То есть - компилятор создает **СТАТИЧЕСКИЙ** массив! Но как? Ведь размер не вычисляется на этапе компиляции.

Comment: Только это не статический, а **автоматический** массив. Вообще вся память переменных делится на 3 области. 1) Статическая (это переменные объявленные с атрибутом **static** внутри функций или переменные объявленные вне функций. Статические переменные размещаются в секциях .data (нинциализированные на этапе компиляции) и .bss 2) Автоматическая. Это переменные, объявленные внутри функций. Они размещаются в стеке. При входе в функцию стек растет на объем переменных этой функции, при выходе уменьшается. 3) Динамическая. Память выделяется (в общем случае вызовом ОС) по запросу в ходе работы

Comment: new/delete (внутри это malloc/free) работают как раз с **динамической** областью памяти. Поскольку ваш массив расположен в автоматической области  (стеке), то к нему нельзя применять delete.

Comment: *`"То есть - компилятор создает СТАТИЧЕСКИЙ массив! Но как? Ведь размер не вычисляется на этапе компиляции."`* -- (повторюсь, не статический, а автоматический массив) компилятор делает машинный код, который вычисляет размер массива (по содержимому переменной cities) и изменяет стек соответственно этому размеру (умные (и добрые) люди из GNU подарили юзерам такую фичу (ее назвали VLA (variable length array))  в виде одного из расширений ([extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions)) языка)

Comment: похожий вопрос [Создание массива в функции на стеке с разным размером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1509121/288358) - почитайте.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш массив статический. Компилятор у вас поступает *нестандартно*, потому что в стандарте такие фокусы не описаны и потому непереносимы.

А реализуется это очень просто — выделением нужного куска памяти в стеке.

Для того, чтобы работало ваше удаление, массив нужно создавать иначе:

```
int ** mas = new int*[cities];
for (int i = 0; i < cities; ++i) mas[i] = new int[cities];
```

Comment: Harry, а откуда компилятор знает, какой кусок памяти в стеке выделить?

Comment: А откуда он знает, какой кусок памяти забрать при `new int[cities]`? Просто он выделяет его не в момент компиляции, а в момент выполнения. Но от этого статический массив динамическим не становится...

Comment: я и сам догадался, что массив статический, но как так происходит? Это же полное противоречие стандарту.. К слову, компилятор gnu gcc и библиотека libstdc++.

Comment: Проверил, clang и libc++ тоже создает этот массив статически. В чем тогда тут нестандартное поведение и непереносимость?

Comment: Выходит, правило, в соответствии с которым размер статического массива обязан быть константой времени компиляции - больше ничего не значит?

Comment: ***В стандарте*** — значит. Возьмите другой компилятор или воспользуйтесь в вашем ПСС ключиками, отключающими его шалости со стандартом. Еще раз посмотрите на второе предложение моего ответа: "**Компилятор у вас поступает *нестандартно***". Претензии — к компилятору. Если кто-то перебегает дорогу или проезжает на красный цвет светофора, вы же не считаете, что ПДД больше ничего не значат?